# How to add headers to the table columns on button click

Tags: javascript, html

I am generating a dynamic table with headers based on user input, and adding columns on click of button. While adding columns on click i want to add header to the column as well. If i click on AppendColumns button it should add column with header.

Demo:

```js
function CreateTable() {
        var rowCtr;
        var cellCtr;
        var rowCnt;
        var cellCnt;
        var myTableDiv = document.getElementById("myDynamicTable");
        var table = document.createElement('Table');
        table.setAttribute("contenteditable", "true");
        table.border = '1';
        table.id = 'myTable';
        var Header = ["Label", "Control"];
                var thead = document.createElement('thead');
                table.appendChild(thead);
         cellCnt = document.getElementById('txtcols').value;
                for (var i = 0; i < cellCnt; i++) {
                    if (i % 2 == 0) {
                        thead.appendChild(document.createElement("th")).
                            appendChild(document.createTextNode(Header[0]));
                    }
                    else {
                        thead.appendChild(document.createElement("th")).
                            appendChild(document.createTextNode(Header[1]));
                    }
                }
        var tableBody = document.createElement('Tbody');
        table.appendChild(tableBody);
        rowCnt = document.getElementById('txtrows').value;
        cellCnt = document.getElementById('txtcols').value;
        for (var rowCtr = 0; rowCtr < rowCnt; rowCtr++) {
            var tr = document.createElement('tr');
            tableBody.appendChild(tr);
            for (var cellCtr = 0; cellCtr < cellCnt; cellCtr++) {
                var td = document.createElement('td');
                td.width = '120';
                td.appendChild(document.createTextNode("Click me, Row:" + rowCtr + " Column:" + cellCtr));
                tr.appendChild(td);
            }
        }
        myTableDiv.appendChild(table);
        }
     function AppendColumns() {
                var tableCell = document.getElementById('myTable');
                for (var i = 0; i < tableCell.rows.length; i++) {
                    var colCell = tableCell.rows[i].insertCell(tableCell.rows[i].cells.length);
                    colCell.width = '120';
                    var insertCell = (colCell, i, 'col');
                }
             }
```

```html
<table contenteditable = "true">
        <tr>
            <td>Row Count</td>
            <td>Column Count</td>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><input type="text" id="txtrows" /></td>
            <td><input type="text" id="txtcols"/></td>
            <td><button onclick="CreateTable()">Create Table</button></td>
            <td><button onclick="AppendColumns()">AppendColumn</button></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    <div id="myDynamicTable"></div>
```

[image: Result Table]

Comment: Your question is not clear, You said you want a column with header.
When I click appendColumn with a table of 3 rows, and 2 column, I got a column with 3 rows, so the first row is considered as header right ? or you want a `<th>` element ?

Comment: after creating a table i am appending extra columns, while adding column its generates only column not with header.

Comment: Sorry I still don't get it, how do you want it to be

Comment: Actually i had already add <th> element in the code, here it only creates table not headers for the table i dont know why?

Comment: Each time you create a table you create it with the same id of "myTable". ID attribute should always be unique. Could you also add a visual representation of your desired result? Is my understanding correct that you want to add another row that is table heading above the newly added table column with your specified name?

Comment: I have added a image, in that i want to add header to the last column. @BambiOurLord

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**try this**
I think you missed to assign the value for variable `cellCnt` in the `CreateTable()` method.

```js
function CreateTable() {
        var rowCtr;
        var cellCtr;
        var rowCnt;
        var cellCnt;
        var myTableDiv = document.getElementById("myDynamicTable");
        var table = document.createElement('Table');
        table.setAttribute("contenteditable", "true");
        table.border = '1';
        table.id = 'myTable';
        var Header = ["Label", "Control"];
                var thead = document.createElement('thead');
                table.appendChild(thead);
                thead.id = 'tHead';
                cellCnt = document.getElementById('txtcols').value;
                for (var i = 0; i < cellCnt; i++) {
                    if (i % 2 == 0) {
                        thead.appendChild(document.createElement("th")).
                            appendChild(document.createTextNode(Header[0]));
                    }
                    else {
                        thead.appendChild(document.createElement("th")).
                            appendChild(document.createTextNode(Header[1]));
                    }
                }
        var tableBody = document.createElement('Tbody');
        table.appendChild(tableBody);
        rowCnt = document.getElementById('txtrows').value;
        cellCnt = document.getElementById('txtcols').value;
        for (var rowCtr = 0; rowCtr < rowCnt; rowCtr++) {
            var tr = document.createElement('tr');
            tableBody.appendChild(tr);
            for (var cellCtr = 0; cellCtr < cellCnt; cellCtr++) {
                var td = document.createElement('td');
                td.width = '120';
                td.appendChild(document.createTextNode("Click me, Row:" + rowCtr + " Column:" + cellCtr));
                tr.appendChild(td);
            }
        }
        myTableDiv.appendChild(table);
        }
     var Header = ["Label", "Control"];     
     function AppendColumns() { 
                var tableCell = document.getElementById('myTable');
                var lastIndex = tableCell.rows[0].cells.length-1;
                var theader = document.getElementById('tHead');
                if(lastIndex % 2 ==1){
            theader.appendChild(document.createElement("th")).
                        appendChild(document.createTextNode(Header[0]));
                        }else{                            theader.appendChild(document.createElement("th")).
                        appendChild(document.createTextNode(Header[1]));

                        }
                for (var i = 0; i < tableCell.rows.length; i++) {
                    var colCell = tableCell.rows[i].insertCell(tableCell.rows[i].cells.length);
                    colCell.width = '120';
                    var insertCell = (colCell, i, 'col');
                }
             }
```

```html
<table contenteditable = "true">
        <tr>
            <td>Row Count</td>
            <td>Column Count</td>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><input type="text" id="txtrows" /></td>
            <td><input type="text" id="txtcols"/></td>
            <td><button onclick="CreateTable()">Create Table</button></td>
            <td><button onclick="AppendColumns()">AppendColumn</button></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    <div id="myDynamicTable"></div>
```

Comment: This solves his problem partially, however the table IDs are still the same and columns  with headings are only added to the first table.